# Why is rbind not working when I use rep()?

Tags: r

I am trying to rbind 2 columns, one that is just a repetition of NA for 20 rows which I did using rep(NA,20) and then another column of data with number that I have ie data <- (1:20).

What I want is just a table of 
NA
NA
NA
NA
NA
NA
NA
1
2
3
obviously with more numbers.

For some reason, when I rbind(rep(NA,20), data), NA only shows up in the first box and not in 20 rows like I want.

I've used this before and it worked fine, so what's going on?

Comment: Could you please provide a MWE with replicable code. It's difficult to understand how the desired result should look like, just from the description.

Comment: `c(rep(NA,20), 1:20)` or `matrix(c(rep(NA,20), 1:20), ncol=1)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do

```
data.frame(V1 = c(rep(NA, 20), data))
```

Or if you need a matrix

```
cbind(c(rep(NA, 20), data))
```

Comment: I want it as rbind, so I tried rbind(c(rep(NA,20), data) but it still only shows with one row of NA instead of 20?

Comment: @tamcle `rbind` does not give you the expected output which is all the values in one column.

Answer (score 0):

This is, what creates the desired column:

```
data <- as.matrix(1:20, ncol = 1)
rbind(as.matrix(rep(NA,20), ncol = 1)
      , data)
```

Example with only five entries in data and the result in one column.

```
rbind(as.matrix(rep(NA,5), ncol = 1)
      , data)
      [,1]
 [1,]   NA
 [2,]   NA
 [3,]   NA
 [4,]   NA
 [5,]   NA
 [6,]    1
 [7,]    2
 [8,]    3
 [9,]    4
[10,]    5
```

Another option:

```
data <- (1:10)
rbind(c(rep(NA,10), data))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
```

You have to keep in mind the dimensions of the individual matrices and also that matrices can only store data of one type. I would suggest to look at data.frames, which can store different data types per column.

Comment: what if i wanted it all in one column?

Comment: Could it be that rows and columns got mixed up? Currently, my code produces one column of the values.

Comment: hmm so I'm actually subsetting data from a table as my 2nd input, so it gives me the error that names do not match since the rep(NA,20) doesn't have a column name. do you know how to fix that?

Comment: I am still not sure if `rbind` is the thing you're looking for. Aren't you trying to put them in a matrix/data.frame with one row and multiple columns?

Comment: the reverse, multiple rows and 1 column

Comment: But that's what's my first solution. Please check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics) on the definition on rows and columns.